# How to add a method for different structs which have one common field in golang

Tags: go, beego

I'm using beego/orm for my app. Here I have 2 models

```
type ModelA struct {
    Guid string `orm:"pk"`
    FiledA string
}

type ModelB struct {
    Guid string `orm:"pk"`
    FiledB string
}
```

I need to add a `Save()` method for each struct. In general, I can create an `Base` struct and mixin it into `ModelA` and `ModelB`, but the orm would not work.

Is there any better solution?

**edit1:** Giving `Save()` code here to make question more clear

```
func (this *ModelA) Save() error {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    guid := guidlib.Generate()
    this.Guid = guid
    _, err := o.Insert(this)
    return err
}

func (this *ModelB) Save() error {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    guid := guidlib.Generate()
    this.Guid = guid
    _, err := o.Insert(this)
    return err
}
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with beego/orm, but is there a reason you couldn't put a tag on an embedded struct? I'm still not sure this will truly help you, since a method operating on that embedded struct won't have access to any other fields of the outer struct.In terms of

Comment: @AndrewN, so in the `func (this *Base) Save()` method, the `this`  varable  is always pointer to `Base`, even if invoking it on a `ModelA` instance? Maybe the Base solution is the wrong way. To make the question more clear, i add the implement of `Save()` method.

Comment: Correct. `this` isn't very idiomatic in Go, though. If the logic is really *exactly* the same, make your Save function not-a-method, and call the object (through an interface). Let me see if I can whip up an example, and I'll post it as an answer, since I'm moving way beyond comments...

Comment: [Here](http://play.golang.org/p/VsxyA5s55a)'s a very simple example of using interfaces to write your `Save` logic once.

Comment: @AndrewN, thank you. If the `interface` could include data fields, like `type IDer interface { ID string }`, the code would be more simple and beautiful.

Comment: Well the whole point of interfaces is that they define behavior, not data structures, but it's pretty common to have structs only make their fields available through a method of the same name, but capitalized/exported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Define an interface. Also, hate to nitpick, while I'm pretty sure you're talking about embedding there isn't a 'mixin' concept that exists in Go. Here's some pseudo code that demonstrates the constructs.

```
type Savable interface {
       Save()
}

// satisfies Savable for ModelA
func (a ModelA) Save() {
      // do something
}

var i Savable
i = SomeMethodThatRetunsMyModel()
i.Save()
SomeOthermMethodThatAcceptsASavableAndCallesSave(i)
```

The embedding approach:

```
type ModelA struct {
    ModelC
    FiledA string
}

type ModelB struct {
    ModelC
    FiledB string
}

type ModelC struct {
    Guid string `orm:"pk"`
}

func (this ModelC) Save() error {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    guid := guidlib.Generate()
    this.Guid = guid
    _, err := o.Insert(this)
    return err
}
```

However, note that `o.Insert(this)` is not going to insert any fields that aren't defined on `ModelC`. As I mentioned in my comment below the type of inheritance structure that might be used where models A and B would reimplement `Save` calling the base classes method upfront doesn't really work well in Go.

The rules for method resolution with embedded types aren't completely clear and can be confusing. You could define one version of `Save` in the embedded structs, redefine it in the embedor and even call it within that method however it doesn't really make much sense to do. I would make a point to avoid embedding if you're still going to have to statically reference the embedded type. For example if I have `ModelA` embedding `ModelC` and in the broader scope I'm having to do `ModelA.ModelC.SomeMethodThatIhaveToReferencExplicitlyToEnsureItsCalled()` then I'm probably making poor use of the feature.

Comment: It's important to note that while using interfaces is probably a good idea, it won't save the author from writing two `Save()` methods, one for each struct. An interface will really only help reduce the code that *uses* `ModelA` and ModelB`, since it can operate on the interface instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `embedding` is not `mixin`. As @AndrewN said, it would writing two `Save()` methods too, and I want to write only once, because saving `ModelA` and saving `ModelB`  have the same logic.

Comment: @alxlx embedding could be beneficial too. You'd still need to use interfaces to keep the calling code generic but if you wanted, you could move all common fields into their own struct and embed that. You could define save there if that subset of the data is sufficient for what you need to do. If you need to write both shared and not shared data in this method, I'd generally recommend against it because it's just not as clear in Go how this works as say in C# or Java where you'd inherit, override and invoke the base method. With embedding method resolution gets muddy and I don't like that.

Comment: @alxlx I'll edit with an example. I didn't read your edit too closely but if that example is more or less complete then I do think it would be good to embed.

Answer (score -2):

No, you can not do this because Golang does not support inheritance. But you can do something like this below:

```
func Save(obj interface{}) error {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    guid := guidlib.Generate()
    r := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
    f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName("Guid") 
    f.setString(guid)  
    _, err := o.Insert(obj)
    return err
}
```

Be careful, it will panic if there is no field "guid"